# how to implement facebook like button on my website for each photo on my page?

Tags: asp.net

I have a page that have 5 to 10 photos of a person, If some user comes into this page he should see facebook "Like" button next to each photo on that page. Please tell me the best to do it?

I have installed Javascript SDk on my site, I can use XFBML also. Just post me some sample code if you have any?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why not do what the manual says ?

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like